# Firstname with capitalized first letter and lowercase all remaining letters

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am new to Salesforce, i do receive a fullname in uppercase letters, how can i extract the firstname from this fullname, capitalize to uppercase only the first letter and lower all remainig letters form the firstname ?

```
Select c.FullName From Contact c
```

I research how to get only the firstname using LEFT( c.Fullname , FIND(" ", c.Fullname , 1) -1)

Thank's in advance

Comment: Are you trying to do this in Apex, Visualforce, a formula field or something else?

Comment: As i am new to salesforce i really do not know about all the concepts, i am trying to edit a journey builder inside the salesforce marketing tool and editing the sql query from it, i will create a new journey builder to query only my own record in the database .

Comment: @Angelo Rigo Take a look at this video, it walks through SQL basics in Marketing Cloud: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BwBzkHQMjr4

Comment: @ÂngeloRigo Salesforce has a lot of products and telling us it's for the Marketing Cloud makes is easier to help you find an answer.

Comment: Thank you for the video @identigral

Comment: Thank you for the advice @Kasper

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Angelo To get the Firstname from Fullname you can use SQL query to split -

```
SELECT Email,
  SUBSTRING(FullName, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', FullName) - 1) AS FirstName
FROM [Contact]
```

Assuming "Fullname" have space after first name.

Once you have the FirstName column updated in the Data Extension, you can then use the AMPscript function - Propercase in the email where you want to show the name. Here is the help document - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/ProperCase.html

Syntax - %%=ProperCase([ColumnName])=%%

Lets assume your column name in the DE is "Firstname" then you need to enter this in the email -

%%=ProperCase([Firstname])=%%

Comment: Thank you @Mradul i will test the solution, glad for you help.